# append li as last-child(2)

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

```
<div class="container">
<div class="tokens">
<ul class="tokenlist list-inline">
<li>
<div class="input">
<input type="text" class="king" placeholder="enter ur mail"> 
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
;$.fn.pressEnter = function(fn) {  
return this.each(function() {  
$(this).bind('enterPress', fn);
$(this).keyup(function(e){
if(e.keyCode == 13)
{
$(this).trigger("enterPress");
}
})
});  
}; 
$('.king').pressEnter(function(){
var inputtval=$('.king').val();
if(inputtval.length>0){
$("ul.tokenlist").prepend('<li>'+inputtval+'&emsp;<i class="cros fa fa-times cros"></i> </li>');
$('.king').val('');
}else{
$(this).attr("placeholder", "write somthing");
}
});
$('.tokenlist').on('click','.cros',function(){
$(this).parents('li').remove();
});
});
</script>
<style>
.king{
    border:0px;
    /*background-color:#eee;*/
}
i.cros{
    font-weight: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tokenlist li{
border: 1px solid #eee;
background-color:#eee;
margin: 5px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
ul.tokenlist li:last-child{
border:0;
background-color:#fff;
}
ul.tokenlist {
border: 1px solid rgb(194, 194, 194);
width: 100%;
margin: 3px;
}
</style>
```

above code i am using prepend,i tried to use append it was not working...append prepend is not my concepet,what ever i enter in inputfild and hit enter it should be display left side of input filde..
in the above code i want to append li as last-child(2) or last but one child and what ever i append that should be left side of input filde,now what ever i append it is aling to left side but it should be left side for input fild [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/bch371ff/)

Comment: Do you need input as left side and append contents as right side?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of prepending the new `<li>`, you need to insert it before the last item in your list. See this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/bch371ff/1/

```
$('<li>'+inputtval+'&emsp;<i class="cros fa fa-times cros"></i> </li>').insertBefore($("ul.tokenlist").children().last());
```

Comment: thanq i got corret answer